# 'Manual' multi-selection in QTableView and partially hidden grid

Tags: qt, qtableview

I know that topic about multi-select arise at least once, but honestly neither can't find it anymore, nor remember that it had and decent solution.

There are two questions I propose to discuss:

1) Creating a behaviour similar to MS Excel cell's selection. So user click one cell in QTableView and gets clicked cell highlighted and in additional several 'dependant' cells change appearance (get selected or just gets highlighted in any way). In Excel it's widely used to show cell formula dependencies.

I know there are several approaches to solve it. Most simple one is to modify view selection with dependant cell in any of appropriate signal handlers (for example QAbastractModelView clicked()). That way does the job but has ugly side effect, that due to fact that signals delivered after redraw of selected cell occurs so dependant selection is drawn after first cell which produce flickering.

Second approach is go Delegate way.. That's also have some issues because you get paintEvent  only for selected cell, so there is not that much you can do about 'dependent' cells. Actually I was able to solve it through this way, by catching on-click, modifying selection and using completely custom delegate which draws everything as soon as complete selection is formed, so actually it skips first redraw, but again I wasn't completely satisfy with results although visually it looked completely right.. mostly because overall TableView response time decreased a lot. Reasons for that is Qt draws native selection right after mouse click received before sending any signals to user classes and in case of this approach paintEvent in delegate arrives after several main loops. So there is a noticeable delay in case of using 'draw selection in delegate' in compare to 'draw native selection'.

I am already starting to think that best option can be completely overwrite most of QTableView to add support for such selection schemas, but may be there are more straight approach?

2) Second question (I put them together because there are something common issues). 
Let say you have a grid representing financial information by months and within a month there are several columns of information, so block of N columns repeated M times. Obvious way to make such grid more readable is to use different style for vertical lines in grid for first data column in each month. Let's say to make them 1-2 pixels wider.

As you cannot specify grid style per cell, what I did was to setGrid(false) and then draw my own grid lines as a cell content in delegate.

But then I faced a problems from point 1. Then you instruct Qt to use delegate on certain cell, before delegate will get a paintEvent Qt clears a background of the cell. And in case of hidden grid the background rect which Qt clears is one pixel bigger then required. Probably it can be consider to be a Qt bug because they dont respect grid visibility, but this results in removing grid lines in neighbour cell, so you have to draw in delegate not only cell own grid, but also recalculate proper cell rectangle, check if Qt made a mistake (by analysing QPainter rect), decide if whats being removed from neighbour cell needs restore and repaint it also. This leads to really complicated delegate logic and I cannot consider it to be a decent solution.

So question 2 can be rephrased as do we know a decent way to style a grid per cell in QTableView?

Answer (score 1):

OMG,so many words,can you just pick the most important info?

Comment: Well if it would be simple question I probably could solve it myself =) it's more a discussion topic, I believe there are professional Qt developers around who faced similar problems. So I just propose to discuss possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like that:

Create a delegate. Subclass `QAbstractTableModel` and reimplement `data` method. Your implementation should return cell text for `Qt::DisplayRole`, but also can return whatever you want if `role` is one of your user-defined roles (like font or color or whatever of cell's text. You can use any role number above `Qt::UserRole`). Your model should emit `dataChanged` signal to notify `QTableView` that the content is changed and should be redrawn.

Then in delegate you just request this data using your overloaded `QAbstractTableModel::data` and draw it the way you want.

Comment: Am I understood you idea right, that as soon as certain cell clicked you 'adjust' let's say some decoration roles for 'dependent' cells so they are not really selected but redrawn because of dataChanged emitted? Interesting approach, but dont you have a visible delay in between selection is drawn and other cells change an appearance?

Comment: I don't think so, because all GUI in qt is in processed in one thread and I don't see the reasons why the redraw in this thread may be postponed. However, if you want to be really sure, you can disable and enable updates with `QWidget::setUpdatesEnabled`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will try that way and inform about results.. about redraw, you are right but Qt also does optimisation around sequential update()/redraw() calls to minimise painting.. so it's not obvious that two updates will be separated paints. But in your solution I believe it's the case. Any nice ideas about grid style per cell? =)

Comment: What I dont like in that approach is that it breaks a bit MVC concept.. let's say you have one model with a lot of numbers and you need to have two views with different dependency rules. For example one with 'same values highlighted' on select and other with 'less then selected highlighted'. Probably that can be solved in more elegant way through proxy model..

Comment: Well, if you look into `QTableView::paintEvent`, you'll see that it uses one grid style for all cells, so in this case, I can't think of anything other than subclassing/reimplementing `QTableView`

Comment: It's obviously a way to go for new development, but a lot of existing forms which loaded on fly using uitools, so reimplementing QTableView will also means to implement a full plugin with adjusting forms.. I was hoping to find more light-weighted solution which could works 'externally' on existing QTableView, but may be reimplementing is faster way to go

Comment: I don't think that it breaks MVC. In your example, I'd used a parametrized delegate which will itself decide whether to draw highlighted cell or not. The reason behind this is that highlighting 'same as selected' and 'less than selected' are not inherent properties of model, compared to something like 'value of selected depends on'

Comment: that's right, but that means that dataChanged should be emitted for whole model. I though that if proxy is used, proxy model can decide about highlighting scheme (so we can have something like SameValueProxy, LessThenProxy etc) and adjust decoration roles, while parent will keep data. So delegate class will take decoration roles from proxy, and also it means that as soon as proxy model receives primary cell selection changed it can decide which other cells needs to be highlighted and emit signals only to changed cells rather then whole grid.